# Question about Colon (:) in Functions

Tags: functions

What do these equations mean?

1) $\ \omega:X(\omega) = x_i$

2) $\ \phi(X): \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $

I'm only familliar with functions such as f(x) = 2x, and have not seen 1 & 2 before.

Comment: I think the correct term is expression rather than equation.

Comment: The second means a function called $\phi(X)$ that takes an input $\omega \in \Omega$ and outputs a real number $y = \phi(X)(\omega)$.  The first just looks incorrect.

Comment: Colon could mean “such that”

Comment: You need to provide more context to give an answer.

Answer (score 4):

When defining a function, as well as saying what it does you also should say what goes into it, and what comes out of it. We call these the domain and codomain of a function. If the domain of a function $f$ is $A$ and the codomain is $B$, then we write $f:A\to B$. To fully define a function, you would specify what $A$ and $B$ are as well as providing a definition of what $f$ does such as $f(x)=2x$. The statement in number 2 is the first half of such a definition, it's telling you the domain and codomain.
Not too sure about number 1 without more context.

Comment: “a specific element $\omega$ such that $X:\omega\mapsto x_i$

Answer (score 0):

One meaning of the [colon](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Colon.html) in mathematics is "such that."

For example, (1) $\ \omega:X(\omega) = x_i$ could be read as "$\ \omega$ such that $X(\omega) = x_i.$"

As noted, in (2), colon can also be used in mathematics to mean a function "maps."